# Why is this invalid syntax within for loop?

Tags: python

I was trying with the below code and got the error:

```
def preprocess(s):
    return (word: True for word in s.lower().split())
s1 = 'This is a book'
text = preprocess(s1)
```

And then here comes the error that

```
return (word: True for word in s.lower().split())
```

is invalid syntax. I cannot find where the error comes from.

I want to put the sequence into this list model:

```
["This": True, "is" : True, "a" :True, "book": True]
```

Comment: That is not a list. you want a dictionary

Comment: Also if you did want a list you'd use `[]`, not `()`, otherwise you'd just be returning a generator expression.

Answer (score 3):

You want to construct a dictionary not a list. Use the curly braces `{` syntax instead:

```
def preprocess(s):
    return {word: True for word in s.lower().split()}
s1 = 'This is a book'
text = preprocess(s1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is place the sequence into a dictionary not a list.
The format for a dictionary is:

```
dictionaryName={
    key:value,
    key1:value1,
}
```

So your code could work like this:

```
def preprocess(s):
    return {word:True for word in s.lower().split()}
s1 = 'This is a book'
text = preprocess(s1)
```